# Is there another way to include slash in requestMapping other than using **

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui

Currently I am using requestMapping such as 
`/test/**`, so I can replace `**` with strings contains slash, such as `/test/p1/p2/test.txt`

But using swagger UI, I can not do the replacement.

Is there any other options to include slash in requestMapping url other than `**`?